# *Image* prediction with GEE AI Platform and gradient boosted tree model

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, image-classification, tensorflow

I am attempting to build a crop classifier with training data from Sentinel-2 imagery over several seasons. I want to use a gradient boosted tree model instead of a neural net.

There are many examples of using TensorFlow and Keras to train a neural network in Python, host it in AI Platform, load the model with [ee.Model.fromAiPlatformPredictor](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-model-fromaiplatformpredictor), and predict on new images with [ee.Model.predictImage](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-model-predictimage).

- [Land cover with TensorFlow](https://colab.research.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/people-and-planet-ai/land-cover-classification/cloud-tensorflow.ipynb)
- [Earth Engine TensorFlow AI Platform](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/Earth_Engine_TensorFlow_AI_Platform.ipynb)
- [Earth Engine TensorFlow Logistic Regression](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/Earth_Engine_TensorFlow_logistic_regression.ipynb)

There are also tutorials for building XGBoost* models locally, deploying the models to AI Platform, and using them to predict on new (tabular) data (but not on images).

- [Getting online predictions with XGBoost](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/getting-predictions-xgboost)

{*} I also tried [tfdf.keras.GradientBoostedTreesModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/decision_forests/api_docs/python/tfdf/keras/GradientBoostedTreesModel) to keep everything in the Google family, but that has [its own issues](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/cannot-prepare-a-tensorflow-decision-forests-model-for-earth-engine/4697). I am agnostic to which package I use, if I can figure out how to use either of them for image prediction.

I have successfully been able to train a model with XGBoost, deploy it and versions to the AI Platform, and re-load it as an ee.Model, at least superficially. However, when I try to use the model to predict on an image, I receive the error:

> Prediction failed: Could not initialize DMatrix from inputs: Please reshape the input data into 2-dimensional matrix.

I know this approach is probably overlooking a critical step - something related to ‘EEification’ in the tutorials above. But I don’t really know how to translate that for an XGBoost model and what I should correct in order to make this work.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
# %% Workspace
import ee
from google.cloud import storage
import xgboost as xgb

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Google Earth Engine Credentials
project_name = 'PROJECT'
bucket_name = 'BUCKET'
location = 'us-central1'

# ee.Authenticate()  # Run this once; Trigger the authentication flow
ee.Initialize(project=project_name)

# %% Explanatory features
aoi = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017").filter("country_na == 'Rwanda'").first().geometry()
season = ('2022-09-01', '2023-03-01')  # represents one season

# Sentinel-2 data
s2 = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
      .filterBounds(aoi)
      .filter(ee.Filter.date(*season))
      .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 60)))  # I perform cloud masking in the full script

# Summarize by season
## Reduces individual imagery to one summary (mean, sd, min, max) for the season for each band
s2_szn_smry = (s2.select("B.*").reduce(ee.Reducer.mean().combine(
        reducer2=ee.Reducer.stdDev(), sharedInputs=True).combine(
        reducer2=ee.Reducer.minMax(), sharedInputs=True)))
predictors = s2_szn_smry.bandNames().getInfo()

# %% Outcome
# Crop vs. non-crop land cover type
outcome_name = 'cropland'

dw = (ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1')
        .filterBounds(aoi)
        .filter(ee.Filter.date(*season)))
dw_crop = dw.select('label').mode().eq(4).rename([outcome_name])  # Equal to 1 if LULC = crop (value of 4); Otherwise equal to 0

# %% Training Data
sample = s2_szn_smry.addBands(dw_crop).sample(
    numPixels=10000,
    region=aoi,
    scale=10,
    dropNulls=True,
    tileScale=8
)

randomized = sample.randomColumn()
training = randomized.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', 0.7))

train_file_name = 'demo_training_data'
train_task = ee.batch.Export.table.toCloudStorage(
  collection=training,
  description=train_file_name,
  bucket=bucket_name,
  fileFormat='CSV'
)
train_task.start()

# %% Reload training data for model
# Load training dataset
bucket = storage.Client().bucket(bucket_name)

train_file_path = train_file_name + ".csv"
blob = bucket.blob(train_file_path)
blob.download_to_filename(train_file_path)

with open(train_file_path, 'r') as train_data:
    training_pd = pd.read_csv(train_data, header=0)

# Explanatory features
train_features = training_pd.filter(predictors)

## All features are already numeric so do not need to convert any categorical features to numerical values
print(training_pd.filter(predictors).shape[1] == training_pd.filter(predictors).select_dtypes(include=np.number).shape[1])

# Outcome
train_labels = training_pd[outcome_name]  

# Load data in DMatrix object
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train_features, train_labels)

# %% Model
param = {
    'objective': 'binary:logistic',
    'subsample': 0.5,
    'sampling_method': 'uniform',
    'eval_metric': 'logloss',
    'eta': 0.01,
    'max_depth': 6,
    'num_parallel_tree': 1,
    'seed': 529
}

model = xgb.train(params=param, dtrain=dtrain, num_boost_round=100)

# %% Upload model to AI platform
# Objects
model_name = "demo_xgb_model"
model_gcs_folder = "demo_xgb"
model_gcs_name = model_gcs_folder + "/" + "model.bst"
model_gcs_path = f"gs://{bucket_name}/{model_gcs_name}"

# Save copy to local drive
model.save_model(model_name + ".bst")

# Copy model to Google Cloud Storage
!gsutil cp ./{model_name + ".bst"} {model_gcs_path}
# !gsutil ls {f"gs://{bucket_name}"}  # confirm it was uploaded

# Deploy model
!gcloud ai-platform models create {model_name} --project="{project_name}" --region="{location}"
# !gcloud beta ai-platform models create {model_name} --project="{project_name}" --region="{location}" --enable-console-logging

# Deploy version
version_name = "v1"
!gcloud ai-platform versions create {version_name} --project="{project_name}" --model="{model_name}" --origin="{f"gs://{bucket_name}/{model_gcs_folder}"}" --runtime-version=2.11 --framework="XGBOOST" --region="{location}"

# %% Load model as ee.Model
model_ee = ee.Model.fromAiPlatformPredictor(
    projectName=project_name,
    modelName=model_name,
    version=version_name,
    inputTileSize=[8, 8],  
    proj=ee.Projection('EPSG:4326').atScale(10),  
    fixInputProj=True,
    outputBands={'maize': {
        'type': ee.PixelType.float(),
        'dimensions': 1
      }
    },
)

# %% Prediction on image - Attempt 1
demo_image = s2_szn_smry.toFloat()
predictions = model_ee.predictImage(demo_image)
pred_sample = predictions.sample(ee.Geometry.Point([29.496140, -2.200098]))  # Check to see if prediction worked, at arbitrary point
pred_sample.getInfo()

# Error: ee.ee_exception.EEException: AI Platform prediction model responded with an error:
# 'Prediction failed: Could not initialize DMatrix from inputs: Please reshape the input data into 2-dimensional matrix.'.

# %% Prediction on image - Attempt 2

# Turn into a 2D array image to try to address last error
array_image = demo_image.toArray(1)
predictions2 = model_ee.predictImage(array_image)

pred_sample2 = predictions2.sample(ee.Geometry.Point([29.496140, -2.200098]))  # Check to see if prediction worked, at arbitrary point
pred_sample2.getInfo()

# Error: ee.ee_exception.EEException: Invalid concatenation axis: 1. Array 0 has only 0 dimensions.
```